# Jupyter not showing whole output

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm currently working on a python object, I would like to see and count the value of a column. I need to see all of it.

To show it im using  code:

```
df['column_name'].value_counts()
```

It show only some of it,

```
864     25
1040    16
912     14
848     12
894     12
        ..
1285     1
1287     1
1288     1
1297     1
2053     1
```

is it possible to show all of the output. Because i need to see all of them? i saw tutorial on youtube with the same code, and jupyter able to show all of the output unlike mine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the default options. use code below. Change the number `500` as needed.

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the option to set the max rows that can be displayed. 
Check the documentation here

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html